# Formatting data that also contains null values in MS Report Builder

Tags: sql-server, null, formatting, reporting

Running SQL Server 2012 Report Builder 3.0. I have a dataset that has a Phone Number which occasionally has Null values. Data obtained using a subquery in my Select statement like this: CellPhone = (select top 1 cp.PhoneNumber from providers.ProviderPhones cp where cp.ProviderID = prv.ProviderID and cp.PhoneTypeID = 24 order by PhoneID desc)  This returns the phone as 1234567890.

The following expression works to format the phone number as nnn-nnn-nnnn:

=left(str(Fields!cellPhone.Value),4) + "-" + mid(str(Fields!cellPhone.Value),4,3) + "-" + right(str(Fields!cellPhone.Value),4)

But when there are nulls, I get #ERROR

So to handle the nulls I tried the following:

=IIf(Fields!cellPhone.Value Is Nothing,"No Value", left(str(Fields!cellPhone.Value),4) + "-" + mid(str(Fields!cellPhone.Value),4,3) + "-" + right(str(Fields!cellPhone.Value),4))

This gives me the same results as above. So then I simplified the expression just to test it:

=IIf(Fields!cellPhone.Value Is Nothing,"No Value", Fields!cellPhone.Value)

Which gives me "No Value" when there is a Null and a non formatted phone number.

Why can't I combine the formatting portion with the Is Nothing test? Or is there a better way to format the phone number? (I tried using the same formatting expression as a Custom Format which removed the nulls but didn't format the phone number). Thanks.

Comment: If you have a value that can be null, you should use COALESCE() around it on the SQL side when you retrieve it from the database (SELECT TOP 1 COALESCE(cp.PhoneNumber, '') AS PhoneNumber FROM providers.ProviderPhones cp...)  This will translate any NULLs into an empty string. Of course, your logic will need to deal with empty stings still, but it's easier than dealing with Nulls.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get this to work by placing the COALESCE outside of the subquery like this: CellPhone = COALESCE((select top 1 cp.PhoneNumber from providers.ProviderPhones cp where cp.ProviderID = prv.ProviderID and cp.PhoneTypeID = 24 order by PhoneID desc),'')